# Evaluation of itinerary in Flåm, Norway for 2 days in summer

Tags: planning, itineraries, norway

We started planning our trip to Norway in July and we allocated full 2 days stay at [Flåm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fl%C3%A5m) (3 nights). We like to do the following things:

1. Kayaking (old king path)
2. Take Flåm-Gudvangen ferry. and get off from ferry at Styvi and hike the old postal route along Nærøyfjorden towards Bleiklindi and
   (get into ferry back and goto Gudvagen). And come back to flåm by
   bus.
3. Take train from Flåm to Myrdal, and cycle back to Flåm. (if it's possible / and planning to take the rented bikes from Flåm).

So what I need to know is how much time those things take? Is it too much to try those all in 2 days?

Answer (score 3):

My answer will not be very specific, because I visited Flåm and Myrdal six years ago.
However, you intend to travel by kayak, foot, ferry, bus, train, cycle.
It sounds a lot for two days, especially given the landscape there. Mountain trains and buses are slow, distances in fjords are longer.

You might also want to indicate when you'll be there, because the day length is also a factor.

Comment: He does say "in summer" (albeit not which months)

Comment: will be there in July. thnkx for the reply.

Comment: Note that cycling Myrdal-Flåm might not be possible before August, as there might be too much snow even in July. In that case, the bike rental shops are closed.

Answer (score 2):

You should remember Nærøyfjorden is not exactly a central place to go. Except the tourism there are almost nothing there.

I think the plan sounds a bit too ambitious. I would say three days, but remember to look at the map (distances). Also the schedules may not fit your plans (lack of boats, ferries and buses).

Bonus: As long as the owners are alive, you will find the smallest post office in Norway in Styvi. There is also a tiny museum there.